# How to install ethernet wall jacks

Tags: networking, internet

I want to install home network but I don't know the code color in the jack

A and B

what is meaning of (( A L1 T Ts   B L2 2 Tx ))

I want to explain this code because rj45 is

crossover

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on youtube. And other sites. But this is a programming site, so please consult google for the best information. (I'am in a nice mood today: http://www.incentre.net/content/view/75/2/) shows it (third example).

Answer (score 3):

See this:

[image]

```
RX : Reception
TX : Trasmission
PR : Pair
```

By the way I'm pretty sure (to be verified) that wall wiring should be straight and not crossover. In charge of the connected PC to provide Xover if necessary. (And most of recent NICs are making the switch automatically so it does not really matter nowadays)

Answer (score 1):

The standard colour coding for RJ45 is:

1. White w/ orange band
2. Orange
3. White w/ green band
4. Blue
5. White w/ blue band
6. Green
7. White w/ brown band
8. Brown

To create a crossover cable (only ever used between two devices of the same type - like PC to PC or Switch to Switch) swap the orange and green pairs at *one end only* to become w/g, g, w/o, bu, w/bu, g, w/br, br

Hardwired connections in the wall should **always** be connected 1 to 1 and not crossed over.  If you ever need a crossover it should always be done using a crossed-over patch cable.  Connections between PCs and Hubs or Switches never need to be crossed over, the switch does that for you.

Comment: Originally you needed Xover for connecting equipment of the same level: PC-PC (level 1), switch/hub-swithc/hub (level 2), router-router (level 3). And I don't remember, but I assume PC-router was Xover too. But that not the case nowadays, most NICs/equipments have built-in switching capacity.

Comment: Gigabit ethernet always has auto-crossover capability. Modern but not gigabit often does as well these days.